# Green Function for Proca Equation

Tags: field-theory, greens-functions, higher-spin

I have tried to find a retarded and advanced Green function for Proca field equation.

### $(\Box - \mu^2)A^{\mu}=J^{\mu}$

where $\mu$ is the mass term.

How I did it:

first: I made Fourier Transformation for $A^{\mu}$ and its inverse, I got it:

### $Ã^{\mu}(k)=\int d⁴x e^{ikx}A^{\mu}(x)$

### $A^{\mu}(x)=\int d⁴k e^{-ikx}Ã^{\mu}(k)$

Analogously

### $\bar{j}^{\mu}(k)=\int d⁴x e^{ikx}J^{\mu}(x)$

The Klein–Gordon equation:

### $(k_0^{2} -\vec{k}^{2} - \mu^2)Ã^{\mu}(k)=\bar{j}^{\mu}(k)$

particular solution of the inhomogeneous equation above, is:

### $Ã^{\mu}= \frac{\bar{J}^{\mu}}{k_0^{2} -\vec{k}^{2} - \mu^2}$

The corresponding Green Function:

### $(\Box - \mu^2)G(x)=\delta (x)$ (may I do this?)

For $\bar{G}(x)$ we have:

### $\frac{\bar{J}^{\mu}}{k_0^{2} -\vec{k}^{2} - \mu^2} \rightarrow \bar{J}^{\mu}\bar{G}(k)$

using $\omega (\vec{k}) = c \sqrt{\vec{k}^{2} + \mu^{2}}$, whe have:

### $\bar{G}(k)=\frac{c^2}{2 \omega (\vec{k})}[{\frac{1}{ck_{0} - \omega (\vec{k})\pm i0_{+}}}-{\frac{1}{ck_{0} + \omega (\vec{k})\pm i0_{+}}}] $

The choice of $+i0_{+}$ or $-i0_{+}$ gives retarded or advanced Green function:

### $G(x) = \frac{c^2}{(2\pi)^2} \int d^{4}k \frac{e^{-ikx}}{2 \omega (\vec{k})}[{\frac{1}{ck_{0} - \omega (\vec{k})\pm i0_{+}}}-{\frac{1}{ck_{0} + \omega (\vec{k})\pm i0_{+}}}]$

My questions:

1 - Is it right?

2 - There's a another (easy) way to find it?

Comment: Beware that the Fourier transform of $\Box A^\mu(x)$ is equal to $-k^2\tilde A^\mu(k)$. Remind that $k^2=k_0^2-{\vec k}^2$. Of course you should take the scalar product $kx$ accordingly : $kx=k_0x_0-\vec x\cdot\vec k$.

Comment: A more basic remark: one cannot add a vector (like $\vec k$) and a scalar (like $k_0$) !

Comment: @V.Rossetto, I wrote it wrong, sorry. I forgot the "^2".

Comment: One question, are you aiming to solve the integral?

If yes, I'm with a problem on it too but at other point (my problem is that I'm finding zero at the end...)

Two good references that may help you:

Bogoliubov Shirkov &15. [Intro to the Theory of Quantized Fields]
Eleftherios N Economou 2.2 [Green's Functions in Quantum Physics]
Greiner 4.4 [Field Quantization]

Comment: About what you wrote.

1 - You forgot the $(2\pi)$ in your def of Fourier Transform and Inverse Fourier Transform.

2 - About the Dif. Eq. satisfied by the Green Function, it's ok. It's exactly the way to do that.

Comment: You may have interest in this question: [link](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45930/evaluating-propagator-without-the-epsilon-trick/82598)

There is made a good reference to Huang 2.9

Comment: @Erich, Thank you. I have been using Bogoliubov's book, But I think that the better way to do that, is using Feynman propagator, because, I had to use general function, above. And I'm aiming to solve the integral, but I started not to do this.